Learning for/from business(es): making it standard for greater community giving
Let's say someone had a business.
How would you book a working session at that business, for the purposes of

learning
entertainment
mental stimulation and idea building

I wonder whether any business cater towards this without providing jobs.
Can you give me some examples of this?
Thanks.

I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about economics.

Businesses would never do that because of three related concepts: 1) market competition 2) industrial espionage and 3) industrial sabotage.
But what you are describing already exists in the form of hobbyist clubs. If you are interested in a hobby, everyone can walk from the street and join.
